# After WordPress export/import, the blog sometimes loads an empty page

Tags: wordpress

I'm talking about http://henrich.ro

Recently I've changed the hosting. It's a WordPress blog. I copied the files through FTP, then exported the database from the old hosting via the WordPress admin panel and imported on the new hosting.

The blog sometimes loads an empty blank page, a fast load, without any error on the log files.

It is because i just copied the files and haven't installed a new wordpress before imported the database and files? I avoided this because I have lots of plugins installed with particular settings.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) for switching hosts with Wordpress. It has a step by step list of things to check.

Comment: i made just like it is written there.

Comment: On chrome for osx I occasionally got `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error.` errors. Doing a bit of google searching came up with [this page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-324-empty-response-on-a-previously-working-site) Maybe that will help you out.